# How to change the page of a view block display programmatically

Tags: views

I have a view with a block display. Is there any way to change the block pager page programmatically?
Currently i am embedding theview using the views_embed_view and i am passing the url arguments. What i need is to pass also the pager index argument also. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get a view programmatically:

```
  $view = views_get_view('view_name');
  $view->set_display('view_block_name');
  $view->set_arguments(array($argument_goes_here));
  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();
  print $view->render();
```

The views object has many functions which can be viewed [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/class/view/7).

You can set current page for the pager with `$view->set_current_page($page);`